# Web Api POST for inserting data with Complex type is always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm quite new to Web-Api concepts. Trying to insert data using the basic project provided by Microsoft (Adding a simple Test Client to ASP.NET Web API Help Page).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/02/adding-a-simple-test-client-to-asp-net-web-api-help-page.aspx

Below is the code for Inserting data into Headoffice table.(HeadofficeID int ,HeadofficeName varchar(50),Notes varchar(1000),Isactive bit)

```
[POST("create")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]HeadOfficeModel headOffices)
        {
            if (_headOfficeBLL.Insert(headOffices) > 0)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, headOffices);
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, headOffices);
        }
```

**Headofficemodel Class**

```
public partial class HeadOfficeModel : AtlAuthenticationModelBase
    {
        public int HeadOfficeId { get; set; }
        public string HeadOfficeName { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

In the front end when i try to send the data from URI or Body only null values are getting inserting. While debugging all i can see in Headoffice model is null values.Below are the different ways i tried to insert data

```
1) {"HeadOfficeName":"TestHO1", "Notes":"notes", "IsActive":true}
2) {"TestHO1", "notes", true}
3) ={"headOffices":{"HeadOfficeName":"TestHO1","Notes":"notes","IsActive":false}}
```

and also tried to change the code as below

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]HeadOfficeModel headOffices)
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]HeadOfficeModel headOffices)
public HttpResponseMessage Post([ModelBinder]HeadOfficeModel headOffices)
```

Been trying to fix this from two days. When i send the data as complex type its not working else as separate parameters (changing the method to accept parameters) its working fine

```
  public int Post(string Name, string Notes, bool Active)
    {
        HeadOfficeModel objHOM = new HeadOfficeModel();
        objHOM.HeadofficeName = Name;
        objHOM.Notes = Notes;
        objHOM.IsActive = Active;
        return _headOfficeBLL.Insert(objHOM);
    }
```

Below is the html code where i m hiting while inserting

```
<script>
  testClientModel = {
    HttpMethod: '@Model.ApiDescription.HttpMethod',
    UriPathTemplate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ApiDescription.RelativePath)),
    UriParameters: [
            @foreach (var parameter in Model.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions)
            {
              if (parameter.Source == System.Web.Http.Description.ApiParameterSource.FromUri)
              {
                    @:{ name: "@parameter.Name", value: "" },
                }
            }
    ],
    Samples: {
      @Html.Raw(@String.Join(",", Model.SampleRequests.Select(s => String.Format("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", s.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s.Value.ToString()))).ToArray()))
    },
    BaseAddress: '@applicationPath'
  };
</script>
```

Can you please help me where am i going wrong. Attaching screenshot.

Entered both in URI and Body just to show that i tried different ways.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5HJ2.jpg)

Comment: Will you share the code from where you are hitting the method ?

Comment: [POST("create")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]HeadOfficeModel headOffices)
        {
            if (_headOfficeBLL.Insert(headOffices) > 0)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, headOffices);
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, headOffices);
        }

Comment: I am not talking about this. I am asking to see from where you are calling this method ? Is it ajax or html form ?

Comment: Hi Mahbubur, below is the code
<script>
testClientModel={HttpMethod: '@Model.ApiDescription.HttpMethod',UriPathTemplate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ApiDescription.RelativePath)),UriParameters:[
@foreach (var parameter in Model.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions){if (parameter.Source == System.Web.Http.Description.ApiParameterSource.FromUri){@:{ name: "@parameter.Name", value: "" },}}],Samples:@Html.Raw(@String.Join(",", Model.SampleRequests.Select(s => String.Format("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", s.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s.Value.ToString()))).ToArray()))},BaseAddress: '@applicationPath'};</script>

Comment: If you write code in comment it won't understandable. you can update your question with this.

Comment: ok Madhbubur..will do..thanks